# using the command gcc with execlp

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork

I have a problem while I use `gcc` with `execlp`.
Here is the result of the execution

```
root@ubuntu:~/sys/TP# ./sys 
shoum.c: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
done2
```

#### My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for fork */
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* for wait */

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
/*Spawn a child to run the program.*/


    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    { /* child process */

           execlp("gcc","shoum.c",NULL);
      // execlp("ls","-liha",NULL);
        printf("not working\n");
            exit(127); /* only if execv fails */
    }
    else
    { /* pid!=0; parent process */
           waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit */
printf("done2 \n");
    }
 return 0;
}
```

PS: When I use other commands like `ls` or `cat` the `execlp` works but it doesn't with `gcc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an argument, it should be:

```
execlp("gcc", "gcc", "shoum.c", (char*)NULL);
```

The first argument is the program to run, the remaining arguments are the `argv[]` array for the program. You were missing `argv[0]`, which contains the name of the program being run. So `gcc` thought it was being run with the name `shoum.c` and no filename parameters.

Comment: And you really should pass `-Wall` and probably `-g` and/or `-O` to `gcc`, and I suggest also passing `-o` *somebinary*